# Concatenate SQL query & echo result

Tags: php, mysql, ms-access

I've got a mdb database with a simple query in it (as proof of concept for a much bigger project/piece of code). I am looking to combine two columns of a table together in a query and display this result using a foreach loop, but can't seem to get it working.

Would anyone have any advice/trips? It would be much appreciated.

```
$dbName = "mydb.mdb";
$db = new PDO("odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ=$dbName; Uid=; Pwd=;");
$sql = "SELECT CONCAT(Address, ' ', Address2) AS full_address from properties";
$sql .= " WHERE Status = 'Available'";

$result = $db->query($sql);

foreach ($result as $row) 
{
   $item = $row["full_address"] . "<br>";
    echo $item;                     
}
```

Many thanks,

Jamie

Comment: MS Access SQL = `Address & ' ' & Address2` not `CONCAT(Address, ' ', Address2)` Watch out for reserved words with that syntax.

Comment: Wow, that simple. Thank you very much Fionnuala!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MS Access SQL =

```
 Address & ' ' & Address2
```

not

```
 CONCAT(Address, ' ', Address2)
```

Watch out for reserved words with that syntax.